# Command line program invoked as a "slave" considered dynamically linked?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cmd, exe

I'm trying to get clarification on exactly what dynamically linked means. I understand if my program links to a separate .dll and makes function calls at run time, that's dynamically linked. But say my program invokes a separate .exe via command line. That .exe can act as a slave by passing "-slave" in the command line and a handle to a window in my app which it communicates to. My program then sends it commands, for example: -dothis or -dothat and the output is sent to my program's window. Is that considered dynamically linked?

I ask because the .exe I'm using via command line is an open-source GPL program and my program is not. My understanding is that if I don't actually link to any GPL libraries, I'm not in violation of the license.

Thanks

Comment: `My understanding is that if I don't actually link to any GPL libraries, I'm not in violation of the license.` Please show me where in the GPLv2 or GPLv3 it ever even talks about "linking". The operative words in the license are much more abstract, speaking of "derivative work" or "forming a work based on the work" etc. The LGPL, on the other hand, does define license terms involving linking, but the LGPL is a separate license, so if the work you are using is GPL-licensed, then this is a moot point

Comment: I verified, one is GPLv2 and the other is LGPLv2.1. I'm not statically or dynamically linking to either in my program, I'm merely invoking them via command line. I'm not modifying them, I'm not even recompiling them. I'm just using versions that are freely available. And for the LGPLv2.1 program, I'm sending it IPC messages via it's command line interface. My understanding is that this is fine. Thoughts?

Comment: The issue at hand should be only your use of the GPL program. For the GPL program, if your use of that program constitutes forming a derivitive work (as defined by copyright law) based on the GPL program, then the GPL requires you release source code of your program as well. What is a derivitive work in this context depends. For example, a commercial IDE that invokes a GPL program to perform compilation could probably claim that the IDE is not a derivitive work of the GPL program because the IDE still functions in the absense of the GPL program.

Comment: Is it possible to use my program without the open-source programs? Yes. In fact, my program already does what they allow me to do also, but they do it much quicker and with more flexibility, so I would prefer to use them. I was debating allowing the user to optionally select using them, then decided against that...and instead I use them by default. I may rethink that just to be safe.

Comment: Programs that I've seen accused of violating GPL mostly do not tell the user and do not make it clear they are using GPL software. Make it a default but make it selectable by some means if the user wants to use a different program with your program. Clearly state the terms in your license and offer the source for GPL components as required by the (L)GPL licenses. If it is part of a commercial product then obviously you should consult a professional legal opinion, as you won't get that on a public message board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that considered dynamically linked?

No. You are dynamically linking to another program only if you load its code in your own process's address space.

Your suggested solution of running the GPLed program as a separate process and then communicating with it using standard IPC facilities is exactly how this problem is solved in the field.